# How to calculate range of IP address given starting address and number of address required

Tags: ip-address, cidr

Given a starting address, say 192.16.0.0, How do I calculate the IP address ranges to allocate  4000, 2000, 4000 and 8000 IP addresses to 4 companies that have requested it (in that order).

Address range  192.16.16.0 to 192.16.23.255 is sufficient for this request or is over allocated or under allocated. Can anybody explain how to solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by IP address range for requests? Do you understand your question?

Comment: I mean using this range of address can I allocate to 4 companies  that had requested ...say I am an ISP

Comment: These companies requested 4000, 2000, 4000 and 8000 addresses each? Please edit the question to clearly articulate this.

Comment: yes u r right... how much range is required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `18000` addresses. `18000 > 2^14`. So you need a `/15` network at least. It looks like you have one `/11` allocation. So it isn't enough.

Comment: then how much will be required.. How do I calculate it.. I need a calculation without over allocating

Comment: You will have to allocate 2^15 = 32k addresses. You can't allocate between powers of two since it'd break hierarchical routing.

Comment: 192.16.32.0 to 192.16.47.255 is sufficient ? I donno calculations !!! Whats the method of calculation .. please explain.. I am a fresher in this field ..

Comment: CIDR notation /15 means the last 15 bits are used for hosts. So if the last 15 bits vary in 192.16.16.0/15, you get 192.16.16.0 - 192.16.255.0